# How to replace or fix water faucet from outside

Tags: plumbing

My water faucet from outside is broken. When I turn off the valve, water still comes out.

I have two questions:

- What would be an approach to try to fix it?
- What would it entail to replace this?

Pictures following

[image]

Comment: put one of these on the tap until you are ready to reaplace ... https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/847259/847259088188.jpg

Comment: Awesome! But how do you replace one of these faucets? They seem to be attached with no screws to the main line inside the house. As if I have to do a hole in the siding?

Comment: depends on how the faucet is attached to the water supply line

Comment: It does not seem to be gushing, so perhaps just replacing the faucet washer would fix it.

Comment: The pic is after I turned off water supply...

Comment: Turned off the water to the whole house or shutoff the water to that faucet from the inside? It's possible the valve on the pipes inside are not completely closing OR you didn't open a faucet to allow the system to drain, so it was a slow drain. Is the faucet sweated to a copper line on the inside of the house?

Comment: Any chance you just need to replace a rubber washer or packing nut or similar?